# Warning C4190 C-linkage-specified

Tags: c++, c, dll

Currently I'm making a dll function using C++. After that, I import this dll to my C# project using `DllImport`. In my C++ project, I got a warning C4190 on my first build process.

```
Warning C4190: 'abc' has C-linkage specified, but returns 
UDT'std::basic_string' which is incompatible with C
```

My current code is as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) std::string abc(std::string targetFile)
  { 
    return somestring;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is telling you that you cannot use STL types for C.

Comment: I don't think std::string and C# string mix well at all. (I'm willing to be educated on this if it is possible.).  Instead, just export export a C function that uses char* as parameters.  Do a web search for "P/Invoke" and you'll find some suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**C++ Part**: You cannot use namespace and C++ object in `extern “C"` interface. Try use more primitive type like `int`, `float`, `char` and pointer (e.g. `char *`) in return values & parameters.

**C# Part**: You can check MSDN [Platform Invoke Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

First requires the Visual C++ compiler with `/clr` option:

```
public ref struct CppLib
{
  static System::String^ abc(System::String^ targetFile)
  { 
    return gcnew System::String(somestring);
  }
}
```

and C# sees it just like a function written in C#.

Second is doable from any language:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) size_t abc(const char* szTargetFile, char* szResult, size_t nResultBytes)
  { 
    std::string targetFile(szTargetFile);
    strncpy(szResult, somestring, nResultBytes);
    return strlen(somestring);
  }
}
```

To use from C#, you'll need a p/invoke declaration using `StringBuilder` for parameters representing output strings.

A third way would be to use `BSTR` (`SysAllocString` and `SysFreeString` API functions).  There's a `bstr_t` wrapper for that in C++.  There's an attribute to set in C# to let p/invoke know the string is a `BSTR`.

The important thing is that both sides agree on how the string is allocated and deallocated.  That means never using C++ implementation-specific allocation functions like a `std::string` constructor/destructor.